# "Gujarati" font does not support while converting div into image

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

i am converting a div to an image and div is having written "Gujarati" language but when i try to convert this div into image, proper output does not come.

**here is my code::**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ConverToImage() {
        var container1 = document.getElementById('container1');
        var img = $('#<%= img.ClientID %>')
        var hfData = $('#<%= hfData.ClientID %>')
        html2canvas(container1, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                $('.img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));         
                img.css("display", "block");
                img.attr("src", img_val.value);
                hfData.attr('value', img_val.value);
            }
        });
    }
   </script>
<div class="senctionLetter" id="container1">
 ......containing "Gujarati"
</div>
   <input type="hidden" id="img_val" class="img_val" />
    <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Generate Image" onclick="ConverToImage();" />
    <img id="img" runat="server" src="" alt="" style="display: none" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Style="display: none;" OnClick="imgbtnYes_Click" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfData" runat="server" />
```

Comment: You cant convert div to image so..far.. you should use HTML 5 <Canvas>  @Sangram

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
html2canvas(container1, {//this line take all inner html tag to convert to canvas from container1 element
```

in your html gujarati text is loose text directly in container1 div.So put gujarati text in one div tag and place this div tag to container1 div

make sure that which element you are converting has only html tags. not direct text or loose text..

change your html

```
<div class="senctionLetter" id="container1">

    <div><!-- add one more div tag  and add  your gujarati line in this div -->
     ......containing "Gujarati"
    </div>

</div>
```